# Distribution of $1/U^2$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(-1, 1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification, uniform-distribution

> Suppose $U\sim \mathrm{Uniform}(-1, 1)$. Let $Y =1/{U^2}$. What is the distribution of Y?

Here is what I have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y \in [1,\infty)\\
P(Y <y) = P\Big(\dfrac{1}{U^2} < y \Big)\\
= 1 - P(U^2 <y)\\
= 1- P(-\sqrt{y} < U < \sqrt{y})\\
= 1 - [F_u(\sqrt{y}) - F_u(-\sqrt{y})]\\
= 1 -\sqrt{y}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Is that correct?

Edited: Based on comments with correct proof:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y \in [1,\infty)\\
P(Y <y) = P\Big(\dfrac{1}{U^2} < y \Big)\\
= 1 - P(U^2 <\dfrac{1}{y})\\
= 1- P(-{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt y}} < U <\dfrac{1}{\sqrt y})\\
= 1 - [F_u(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt y}) - F_u(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt y})]\\
= 1 -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: How does the 3rd line follow? Notice that your final answer is *negative* for $y > 1$.

Comment: Oh I see my error. It should be $P(Y<y) = P(U^2 < \dfrac{1}{y})$

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then your final result will be $P(Y < y) = 1 - y^{-1/2}$ for $y > 1$ (and of course is 0 when $y \leq 1$).

Comment: @user1773010 You might consider adding the new version of the proof  to the bottom of your answer, so that future readers might more easily find it -- this is an interesting question that could help many people understand how the "arithmetic" of random variables works.

Comment: *Reality check:* Then $F_Y(1) = 1-\sqrt{1/1} ~=~0$ and $F_Y(\infty)=\lim\limits_{y\to\infty} 1-\sqrt{1/y~}~=~1$ as desired.